# General question on minimizing a function with complex Nonlinear Constraints using fmincon

Tags: matlab, optimization, constraints, nonlinear-optimization, minimization

Let fun = X(1)*X(2)*X(3) - X(4)*X(5) + X(1)^(2)

parameter vector X = [X(1),X(2),X(3),X(4),X(5)]

Constraints:

1. X(1) > 0;
2. X(1)-(X(4)*X(3)) <= X(2) <= (2-X(3))/3;
3. X(4)*X(3)*(X(2)-((1-X(3))/2)) <= X(1)(X(2)-X(1)+(X(4)*X(3)));

when the constraints are simpler I can make the appropriate A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nonlcon vectors or matrices depending on the situation. But how to approach when the constraints are complex as above.

Comment: You may want to look into the problem-based optimization approach: https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/solve-constrained-nonlinear-optimization-problem-based.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use **Penalty method** as a general approach to solve any constraint problem. there are lots of information on the web regarding Penalty method  like [this](https://web.stanford.edu/group/sisl/k12/optimization/MO-unit5-pdfs/5.6penaltyfunctions.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your function so that a large value is added each time a constraint is violated.  This is not elegant, but it would be easy. Each constraint is inverted, and 10^6 is added to the function return value if the inverse of a constraint is true.  I tried this method. It doesn't work well, probably because the discontinuities in the function cause problems for the built-in routine fmincon(). Here's what not to do:

```
function Z = frbeginner2(x)
%FRBEGINNER2 Function to minimize
%   x(1:5) = model parameters
%   Function frbeginner2() is to be minimized subject to constraints
Z=x(1)*x(2)*x(3)-x(4)*x(5)+x(1)^2 ...
    +1e6*(x(1)<=0) ...
    +1e6*(x(1)-(x(4)*x(3))>x(2)) ...
    +1e6*(x(2)>(2-x(3))/3) ...
    +1e6*(x(4)*x(3)*(x(2)-((1-x(3))/2))>x(1)*(x(2)-x(1)+(x(4)*x(3))));
end
```

A much better solution is to read the Matlab help for fmincon(). It has an optional argument *nonlcon*, which is the name of a function that returns 2 arrays, *c* and *ceq*: the values of equations for the inequality constraints (if any), and the values of the equations for the equality constraints (if any). The first constraint, x(1)>0, is implemented by setting the lower bound for x(1) to 0, and function frbeginCon() takes care of the other constraints.  There are no equality constraints, so the value of 0 is returned for *ceq*. I tried calling fmincon() with the function below for nonlcon, and had good results, for many random starting points.

```
function [c,ceq] = frbeginCon(x)
%FRBEGINCON Constraints specified by rbeginner on stack overflow, 2021-01-15
%   x1..x5 = model parameters
%   These are the constarints on function frbegin0().
%   Constraints: 
%   1. X(1) > 0;     %handle this constraint by set lb(1)=0
%   2. X(1)-(X(4)*X(3)) <= X(2) <= (2-X(3))/3;
%   3. X(4)X(3)(X(2)-((1-X(3))/2)) <= X(1)(X(2)-X(1)+(X(4)*X(3)));
%   Convert each constraint to equation that is <=0 when constraint is met.
%   2a. X(1)-X(4)*X(3)- X(2) <= 0
%   2b. X(2) - (2-X(3))/3 <=0
%   3.  X(4)*X(3)*(X(2)-((1-X(3))/2)) - X(1)*(X(2)-X(1)+X(4)*X(3)) <= 0
    x1=x(1); x2=x(2); x3=x(3); x4=x(4); x5=x(5);
    c=[x1-x2-x4*x3, x2-(2-x3)/3, x4*x3*(x2-((1-x3)/2))-x1*(x2-x1+x4*x3)];
    ceq=0;

end
```

and the function to minimize is just

```
function z = frbegin(x)
%FRBEGIN Function specified by rbeginner on stack overflow, 2021-01-15
%   x1..x5 = model parameters
%   Minimize function frbegin() subject to constraints.
    z=x(1)*x(2)*x(3)-x(4)*x(5)+x(1)^2;
end
```

Comment: I tried the method I proposed above, and it is not so great, for some ranges of allowed values of the parameters. The problem I encountered is that in 10-20% of random starting points I tried, fmincon() (Matlab's function minimization routine) gives up, because the number of allowed tries (500) has been exceeded. And the reason, I think, is that the function I proposed has discontinuities. Discontinuities cause problems for a routine like fmincon() that tries to go downhill in a rational way.

Comment: fmincon() has an optional argument "nonlcon", which is the name of a function that returns two arrays: the inequality constraint equations and the equality constraint equations.  Rewrite your inequality constraints so that each one is an equation which is <=0 when the constraint is met. Your example has no equality constraint equations, so you can return a 0 for the equality constraint array.  See the fmincon() help in Matlab for details and an example.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the help. I went down the road suggested by @Erwin Kalvelagen. It's a very good approach for anyone else as well. This is how I did it

Creating an empty problem

```
prob1 = optimproblem
```

Defining Optimization variables with bounds

```
    x1 = optimvar("x1", "LowerBound",0);
x2        = optimvar("x2","LowerBound",0,"UpperBound",1);
x3     = optimvar("x3","LowerBound",0);
x4      = optimvar("x4","LowerBound",0,"UpperBound",1);
x5     = optimvar("x5","LowerBound",0,"UpperBound",1);
```

Creating an objective function

```
edit function
```

Creating optimizing expression

```
obj = fcn2optimexpr(@function,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)
```

Assigning Objective function

```
prob1.Objective = obj
```

Setting constraints

```
constr1 = x1 - (x4*x3) - x2 <=0;
prob1.Constraints.optim1 = constr1;
constr2 = x2 - ((2-x3)/3) <=0;
prob1.Constraints.optim2 = constr2;
constr3 = (x4*(x3))*(x2-((1-x3)/2))-(x1*(x2-x1+(x4*x3)))<=0;
prob1.Constraints.optim3 = constr3;
```

Looking at the problem again to check

```
showproblem(prob1)
```

Setting the Initial conditions

```
x0.x1 = 0.01;
x0.x2 = 0.15;
x0.x3 = 0.20;
x0.x4 = 0.20;
x0.x5 = 0.5;
```

Solving the problem

```
[sol,fval,exitflag] = solve(prob1,x0)
```

Hope this helps. Thank you @Mansour Torabi and especially @ rosewc for help.